# Mixed Content: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS について

Tags: javascript, https

コンソールログで下記エラーが表示されます

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/1/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'https://example.com/2/'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

---

**Q1.「This request has been blocked」の対象について**

・ブロックされているリクエストは何ですか？
・ファビコン表示だけ、それともHTML表示やjs処理自体もブロックされているのでしょうか？
・このページで記述しているAjax処理がうまくいかないのですが、この件と関係がある可能性はありますか？

---

**Q2.URLについて**
・URLが2つ記載されているのですが、違いは何ですか？
・原因となっていると思われるfaviconが見つからないのですが、このエラーからどこにある見当をつけることは出来ますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ページが https で読み込まれているのに対して、favicon などのその他のリソースの一部が http で読み込まれているため[混合コンテンツ](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content?hl=ja)となり、http で読み込まれているリソースはブロックの対象になります。おそらく、Ajax によって読み込まれているリソースにも http のものがあるのだと予想します。
2. `https://example.com/1/`はページのHTMLで、`https://example.com/2/`（おそらく実際は http でしょうが、）はブロックされているリソースです。仮に favicon を https で読み込もうとして見つからない場合は 404 の表示が行われると思うので、favicon ファイルの有無を確認をする前に通信自体をブロックしているのだと思われます。[こちらのページ](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content?hl=ja)を参考に、まずはリソースのプロトコルをすべて https にすることをおすすめします。